How can I remove only one hyphen from text string
I insert meeting names into a table, from an RSS feed.
When inserting the meeting name into the table, I format the name to be in the fashion down below:
    INSERT INTO dbo.Meeting
    SELECT 
        a.MeetingID
        --e.g. Board of Public Works - January 24, 2024  << REMOVE THE DATE
    ,   FORMAT(a.MeetingDate,'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt') + ' - ' + LEFT(a.MeetingName, CHARINDEX('-', a.MeetingName) - 1) MeetingName
    ,   MeetingTitle
    FROM

I end up with meeting names like:
11/20/2024 05:00 PM - Transportation Commission 
11/20/2024 04:30 PM - Board of Public Works 
11/18/2024 05:30 PM - Plan Commission 
11/18/2024 04:30 PM - Finance Committee 

There is an issue with names that come from the RSS Feed that containt two hyphens such as:
City-County Homeless Issues Committee - December 2, 2024

When a meeting name contains two hyphens, then I end up with meeting names like:
MeetingName (formatted name)  MeetingTitle (original name)
12/22/2024 04:30 PM - City    City-County Homeless Issues Committee - December 22, 2024
11/14/2024 03:30 PM - City    City-County Homeless Issues Committee - November 14, 2024

How can I change the code so that I can have the part City-County with a hyphen, but still remove the hyphen before the date as it comes from the rss feed?
Any help is appreciated.
I tried this way that seems to work, but is not elegant:
--Uncomment whichever string assigned to @myText you want to test code for.
DECLARE @myText as varchar(100) = 'Police Civilian Oversight Board Community Engagement Subcommittee - December 12, 2024'--
--DECLARE @myText as varchar(100) = 'City-County Homeless Issues Committee - December 2, 2024'
SELECT 
       CASE 
            WHEN @myText LIKE '%-%-%' 
                THEN FORMAT(GETDATE(),'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt') + ' - ' + LEFT(@myText,CHARINDEX('-',@myText,CHARINDEX('-',@myText)+1)-1)
                ELSE FORMAT(GETDATE(),'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt') + ' - ' + LEFT(@myText, CHARINDEX('-', @myText) - 1)  
        END AS MeetingName


While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Are you saying that you need to find the last index of a character? Find index of last occurrence of a sub-string using T-SQL may have what you need.

Remove all text after last dash from meeting name
INSERT INTO dbo.Meeting
SELECT 
        a.MeetingID
        --e.g. Board of Public Works - January 24, 2024  << REMOVE THE DATE
    ,   FORMAT(a.MeetingDate,'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt') + ' - ' + LEFT(a.MeetingName, Len(a.MeetingName)-CHARINDEX('-', Reverse(a.MeetingName))  ) MeetingName
    ,   MeetingTitle
    FROM a

fiddle



MeetingID
MeetingName
MeetingTitle




1
11/20/2024 05:00 PM - Transportation Commission
title1


2
11/20/2024 04:30 PM - Board of Public Works
title2


3
11/18/2024 05:30 PM - Plan Commission
title3


4
11/18/2024 04:30 PM - Finance Committee
title4


5
12/02/2024 08:00 AM - City-County Homeless Issues Committee
title5




Thank you, it works. I tried also some code I entered as part of the question under UPDATE, in case you want to see what I tried as well.

I would need a wider variety of examples to verify the solution. What do you want to see if there are 3,4,5,... or more hyphens?  see https://dbfiddle.uk/HXdYmpP_
